# How do I enable mirror (clone) display mode on login screen? (gdm3)

Tags: multiple-monitors, login, display, gdm

My monitor is often turned off when I log in (I use the TV instead). I usually use screen mirroring (cloning) when logged in. But on the login screen, the mirroring doesn't work. Thus in my TV, I don't see the login form :( (the form is on the monitor which is turned off)

How can I enable mirroring in login screen? (afaik, I use X display manager, GDM3 greeter - standard Ubuntu 20.04 LTS).

Comment: An alternative is always to use a different DM.  I decided I liked `sddm` as it shows the login on all displays allowing me to have monitors turned off :)

Comment: LigthDM maybe a good alternative too.